# PHP extract only 4digit numbers from string containing 4digit,5digit,6digit numbers

Tags: php, regex, string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6FGV.jpg)i have tried many php functions like strpos(), preg_match() but none of them works. i have a string

i want to extract only the four digit number which is 1234.

```
<?php
 $texxt="abcd1245 784563 1234 98756 kfg7456178";
 $results=array();
 preg_match('/[0-9]{4}/', $texxt, $results);
 print_r($results);
 ?>
```

but the above code return 1245 instead of 1234.if i remove the abcd1245 then the out put is 7845.the actual string is very large it containg more than 200 numbers like above. i want only the exact 4 digit number.  is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Not sure why you _edited out_ your attempt, since the [help] states you should provide your attempt.

Comment: yes it worked, can you expalin what are those b?

Comment: i didnt intentioanlly remove the code, it a mistake

Comment: The `\b` is a word boundary. It matches the 'edges' of a word. Now, this will still match non-alphanumeric characters (such as `-` for example). So it would still match the string `-1234`. If this is not what you want, then you can use `\s` for whitespace instead of `\b`.

Comment: in my actual string there is 4digit number with and without spaces, like "1234" and "  1234  ", will the regex work in that case too?

Comment: Using `\b` will, `\s` will not. You could do something like `(?:\b|\s)` to match either a word boundary **or a** whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have more than 200 numbers then use below code:

```
<?php
 $texxt="abcd1245 784563 1234 3421 98756 kfg7456178";
 $results=array();
 preg_match_all('/\b\d{4}\b/', $texxt, $results);
 print_r($results);
?>
```

> [**preg_match**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) check for only one occurrence, where as [**preg_match_all**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) check all occurrences.
>   For regex explanation please refer **[doc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place boundaries on both sides of your pattern.

```
\b\d{4}\b
```

An alternative would be to use `\s` instead of `\b` for whitespace - because boundaries will match other non-alphanumeric characters. Depends on exactly what you're looking for.

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/w6iW7n/1/)